# Using jdbc I am using oracle plsql function to retrieve result set, it is not giving me all records in java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
    CallableStatement stmt = null;
    String sql = "begin ? := TEST.USER_LIST.queryByUser(?,?,?,?); end;";
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql);
        stmt.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
        stmt.setString(2, "user1");  stmt.setInt(3, 1); // offset
        stmt.setString(4, "Update_Date");  stmt.setString(5, "DESC");
        stmt.execute();
        if(stmt.getObject(1)==null) {
            System.out.println("Null value");
        } else {
            rs = (ResultSet) stmt.getObject(1);
            int i = 0;
             while (rs.next()) {     i++;    }
             System.out.println("rs size: " +i);
            stmt.close();
            rs.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        try { rs.close(); stmt.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {}
    }
```

OUTPUT:
rs size: 19

**PROBLEM: Total rows return by this code is 10 less than rows in db
if 50 rows in db it shows 40, if 30 it shows 20, if 9 its shows 0.**

Comment: Does your stored procedure return the right result with the above parameters ?

Comment: Catching Exception without handling it is a bad idea. Can you try printing the exception, to make sure your loop is not interrupted there?

Comment: Yes Berger, When I call it from TOAD or SQLDeveloper it gives me right result. And also I have the code to handle the exception in catch block.

Comment: WardC, I have the code to handle the exception in catch block, and the the loop is running fine. every time it eliminates 10 rows only.

Answer (score 0):

- You need one of ResultSet (rs) types: `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE`
  or `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` for that to work
- Usually you count the ResultSet starting from `rs.beforeFirst()` so you count the first element to.

---

```
int size = 0 ;
if (rs != null){  
    rs.beforeFirst();  
    rs.last();  
    size = rs.getRow();
}
```

My suggestion is to make a SELECT COUNT(*) inside the stored procedure

Comment: Hi Cassian, Thanks for the quick reply, How can I get `ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE or ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE` int size = 0 ;
`if (rs != null){  
    rs.beforeFirst();  
    rs.last();  
    size = rs.getRow();
}` is giving exception.  Also I added count(*), it is giving me correct count.

Comment: Here is the exception .`rs.beforeFirst()` java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for forward only resultset : beforeFirst

Comment: replace line 5 : stmt = conn.prepareCall(sql); with stmt=conn.prepareCall(sql, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY) also check this link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97339_01/doc/java.816/a81354/resltse2.htm#1018228

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, it was ojdbc jar issue, was using ojdbc6, now have replaced with ojdbc14. after jar change it is working fine, Thanks all for reply.